# BASH Check if variable match (or not) regexpr

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

I need a help to find out how to check if a variable matches a defined regexp. Let's say I have the `VAR1="Abcd,1234"` and all vars have to match the regexpr bellow. As we see, my var does not match as it has a comma, so how to check?
I have created the if statement below, but did not work:

```
IF [[ ${VAR1} == ^[a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]:";'?] ]]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to properly use the `\` escape character in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

regex="^[^,]*[^ ,][^,]*$"
var="$1"

if [[ "$var" =~ $regex ]]
then
    echo "matches";
else
    echo "doesn't match!";
fi
```

That check some string does not have comma..

Comment: The regex is overly complex `^[^ ,]+$` would have been enough to ensure at least one char not space or comma (to have the exact same behavior as yours).

Comment: @Tensibai the two regular expressions are not the same.  johnnynemonic's expression will match the string `'   x   '` where yours will not.  However, I agree that your regular expression matches the OP's intention.

Comment: @JEarls To be honest I didn't check the question regex,  just that the regex in the answer sounded overly complex to my eyes